# The html element name of [ p-dataTable ] must be in lowercase <tagname-lowercase>

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I am working on angular 2 app and for grid I am using http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy
I am able to load grid on my html template but when I am building the application or compiling it I am getting the error

```
The html element name of [ p-dataTable ] must be in lowercase <tagname-lowercase>
```

I am using webpack,tslint.json,polyfills.ts.

I am wondering how nobody faced this issue or do I need to add anything to tslint.json file to suppress the
error since tag name is with dash-case + camelcase

Comment: Related: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14696

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't specified the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA on your app module, you should do that.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

and then add this line after providers -

```
 schemas: [  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA   ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack and have an **htmlhint.json** file check the `tagname-lowercase` property is set to false to prevent uppercase characters causing compile issues

i.e.

```
{
  "tagname-lowercase": false
}
```